# Django Pagination return json

Tags: django, django-pagination

I'm here with a problem that does not quite know how to solve.
I have this query:

```
result = json.dumps([a.get_json() for a in Player.objects.filter(name=namepost)])
```

But now I want to return the result with paging, and do not really know how to do ... I've been seeing in the documentation to use the Paginator.

But for example when I do this

```
p = Paginator(result, 2)
    print p.count
```

Gives 1609 ... and the result of the query is 3 records.

Someone can help me?

Comment: It may be better and easier to paginate first and then create the json.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I managed to solve, so I did: http://plnkr.co/edit/k7pdO5o2EBv59OB2Ak1S

Comment: @Helio Can you put your solution as an answer and accept it?